# Why compiled APK does not respect minSdkVersion?

Tags: android

I have created a sample project from an Android Studio with `minSDKVersion=17`. I opened compiled APK from `app\build\outputs\apk\` as a zip file and went to `res` directory. It contains a lot of directories for legacy stuff of versions older than minSDK. Why? It holds bogus 43 KB that will be never used.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vectordrawable.lelisoft.com.showvectordrawable"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

APK:

1. res\color-v11
2. res\drawable-mdpi-v4
3. res\layout-sw600dp-v13
4. res\mipmap-hdpi-v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those directories will be valid on API Level 17+ devices. 17 is higher than 13, 11, and 4. Android apps might pull resources from those directories, if there is not a resource that is a [better match](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

Comment: Ok, they can be used. There is for example res\color-v11\abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark.xml. Do you mean that it is present in APK for all Android legacy versions since v11  until the one that introduced them?

Comment: @LeosLiterak: AFAIK, that particular resource comes from `appcompat-v7`, and so it will not exist in APKs that do not use `appcompat-v7`. That particular resource is not part of the Android SDK, AFAIK.